# PHP showing contents of php file instead of running it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter app that works on one server (IIS 6) just fine. I'm moving it to a new server (IIS 7) and I'm having a strange problem. I'm using a IPTC script as an auto-loaded model. When I try to visit the app, I see this, which is contents of the iptc.php file:

[image]

When I view the PHP file, this is what the code looks like:

```
class Iptc extends Model {
    var $meta=Array();
    var $hasmeta=false;
    var $file=false;

    function Iptc($filename = false) {
        parent::Model();

        $size = @getimagesize($filename,$info);
        $this->hasmeta = isset($info["APP13"]);
        if($this->hasmeta)
        $this->meta = iptcparse ($info["APP13"]);
        $this->file = $filename;
   }
```

So I'm now wondering why when the page loads, you see "hasmeta = isset..." instead of $this->hasmeta. Would that mean there's something wrong with $this?

Comment: Have you tested with simpler php? try creating a test page with just an echo command

Comment: This only happens when I load the IPTC class. Whether I autoload it or use $this->model->load('iptc'); I just get the contents of the file returned.

Comment: I just tried echo'ing (echo iptc), I get the same result. Everything after $this-> from the 10th line I posted above ($this->hasmeta = isset($info["APP13"]);) is printed.

Comment: do you have istalled GD library extension?

Comment: Ack, I figured it out. The iptc.php file uses the PHP short tag <? instead of <?php. When I change it to <?php, it works. Now why would that be?

Comment: check your configurations on php.ini, short tag needs to be enabled sometimes

Comment: That happens because the short tag is not compatible with XML and they deprecated it.  It's supported so old sites can still run, but you have to manually set it on.  Only the long <?php tag is on by default.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli They actually decided not to depreciate short tags... Short tags will continue to be valid PHP in future versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, I figured it out. The iptc.php file uses the PHP short tag